# Not able to send a .bin file from computer to the micro-controller via UART, STM32F415

Tags: terminal, uart, keil, flash-memory, stm32f4

I am trying to send a file(.hex file) from my computer to the micro-controller's internal flash. For time being I am using Hercules terminal to send file. My UART responds to the data sent.

My internal flash memory sector is 128Kbytes and my file is about 50Kbytes , so space is not a problem.

While sending .hex file upto a certain point in file the data gets transferred but after a while it stops . I don't understand why.

To slow it down , I have tried my UART baud rate form 115200 to 2400.

Below is the code:

```
while(1) 
    {
        i = 0;
        int c;
        char str[256];
        printf("\n> ");
        do
        {
            c = fgetc(stdin);
            if(c=='\n')
                break;

            if(c!=-1)
            {
                str[i++] = c;
                delay(10);
            }

        }while(1);
        //str[i]='\0';
        //printf("Got..%s\n",str);
        int j = 0;
        while(j < i-1)
        {
        uint64_t data;
        uint64_t *pData = (uint64_t*)(str + j); //

        //data = *((uint64_t*)&str[i]);
        //++pData;
        data = *pData;

        if (HAL_FLASH_Program(TYPEPROGRAM_BYTE, start_address, data) != HAL_OK) {
                HAL_FLASH_Lock();
                }else
                {
                    //printf("\nSuccess: Writing a byte at (%x) ==> %c ",start_address,*((char*)&data));
                }
                delay(10);
        //data++;
                start_address=start_address+1;  
                j++;
            }
}
```

Below I am attaching my Hercules terminal image :

[image]

Comment: 1) Can you format this code so it's remotely readable? 2) If this _is_ a binary file as per the question title, how can you guarantee it contains frequent enough 0x0a bytes (i.e. '\n') to not overrun the buffer; if on the other hand it's not, do you really want to flash raw ASCII characters without decoding them back to bytes? 3) Without any kind of flow control, what happens to characters which arrive whilst you're in the programming loop? 4) Why dereference an unaligned `uint64_t` pointer (which is pretty much guaranteed to fault) when you only need a byte? There is **so** much wrong here...

Comment: 1.I don't understand when you said format this code so it's remotely readable.
2. No the bin file doesn't have \n
3. So what kind of flow control is required.
4. I dereference it because the HAL API , HAL_FLash_Program() take uint64_t as one of the argument. please suggest a better options

Comment: You're confusing the concept of *".bin"* (or image) file with what you seem to actually have, an Intel hex file. It's possible to convert one to the other, but they are not synonymous or interchangeable names (as you incorrectly use them).